# Can I install BackTrack5 and Ubuntu 11.04 on a single external hard drive?

Tags: operating-systems

Is is possible to install BackTrack5 and Ubuntu 11.04 on a single external hard drive(seagate)?

If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking if you can have both Operating Systems installed on one hard disk? The answer is yes, if you have multiple partitions on the disk. If you have two partitions, one for Ubuntu and the other for BT, they'll operate independent of each other. Either one gives the option to install the GRUB bootloader which will allow you to choose which OS to load when you turn the machine on.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have both Operating Systems installed on one hard disk? Damn Right !

Could you please explain more ? How can I create Multiple Partitions ?

And what is grub boot loader ?

Should I set it up from ubuntu ?

I'm Completely Bamboozled ! Please Help :(

Thanks

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/switching/dualboot.html
This link will give you pretty much everything you need to know. It's mostly about dual booting Windows and Ubuntu, but the principles are the same for dual booting Ubuntu and BT. Knowledge is power! Good luck!

Comment: Note: the documentation is for 8.04, so the utility may look different than the partitioning utility in the latest Ubuntu release. But once again, learn the principles behind what you're doing and you'll be much better off than just blindly following a how-to guide.

Comment: And let me add one more thing -- If you're installing BT just because you heard about a cool hacking utility that it has, please don't. I'm assuming this only because the people that would normally use the tools within BT generally know about HDD partitions and boot loaders. If you're using it for educational purposes, let me warn you that you might be a little overwhelmed and there are better/easier alternatives to learning Linux. Once again, this assumption comes simply from the nature of the question asked. If that's the case, don't become just another 'script kiddie'...

Comment: Hi , I'm regretful ! Because last night i wanted to install bt but i encounter the problem and it caused my ubuntu deleted with all tools and updates :(( now i'm sad !!! I formatted hard drive fully and i'm going to install ubuntu again because with bt I encounter error about the cd /dvd can't ...

Comment: If it deleted your Ubuntu install, that means you did the partitioning incorrectly. Since you're starting over from scratch, when you install Ubuntu don't use the full disk. Do a custom partition set up, use only about half of the hard drive, make the mount point "/" and the filesystem ext4. Then make another partition that's 1 or 2 GB that's a "Swap" partition. Then install. After it's done, do the BT install and yes the remaining space on the disk. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you are asking.  If you want to install BT5 on Ubuntu then you could install it in one of the myriad of virtual machine options you're given.

Otherwise you could try adding the repos

```
> Type: Binary URI: http://source.repository.backtrack-linux.org
> Distribution: revolution Components: main microverse non-free testing
> 
> Type: Binary URI: http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org
> Distribution: revolution Components: main microverse non-free testing
> 
> Type: Binary URI: http://all.repository.backtrack-linux.org
> Distribution: revolution Components: main microverse non-free testing
```

Your best bet would be to go to the backtrack website and check the forums for compatibility.